# Google Api requires userId before I have access_token

Tags: .net, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I received my `authorization code` and want to exchange it to `authorization token` on the server. .NET Google API has `ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync` method in the flow class. Seems like what I need but it requires userId as one of its arguments.

```
var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        {
            ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "...",
                ClientSecret = "..."
            },
            Scopes = new[] { "some scopes" },
        });

flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync(userId, code, "redirect url", CancellationToken.None); //exchange token requires userId
```

So am I supposed to register a user before I receive an authorization token? But I can't do it before I get his Google profile information (and I need a token for this).

Unfortunately there's no documentation for .NET client but [documentation for other languages](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) (search for "After the web server receives the authorization code" on the page to get to a relevant part) does not mention userId.

So either I'm trying to use a wrong method or .NET Api is wrong or I just miss something obvious.

Comment: are you using the Google .net client library?  Please post your code so we can help you address your problem.

Comment: @DaImTo, updated my post

Comment: which api are you planning on accessing?   There is loads of documentation for the .net client library I have written a lot of it.  I guess you just need to know where to look .

Comment: @DaImTo, I'm going to do three things: authenticate, get user profile and then use user's calendar using offline access_type (that's actually another problem: I don't see a way to specify an offline access type in the flow).

Comment: I am wondering where you have found that code it looks more like java code then the .net client library.

Comment: @DaImTo, that's a combination of code from many places :) But it's definitely .NET

Comment: you must have missed my website and my huge compilation of sample code on GitHub.  Weird there is no .net sample code for google calendar.

Comment: @DaImTo, could you please provide any relevant links to samples? I only found official samples and they're not great :(

Comment: Note: They are generated they are not fully tested if you find bugs just report them I will squish them on my next round of bug extermination https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/Genreated-samples1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with just getting the profile info of a user.

There are two APIs you can use for this People API and google+ API.

The following method will request access of the user.   each user chan be changed by sending a different username the credential information will then be stored in %appData%  you can read more about this [here](http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method requests Authentcation from a user using Oauth2.  
    /// Credentials are stored in System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal
    /// Documentation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientSecretJson">Path to the client secret json file from Google Developers console.</param>
    /// <param name="userName">Identifying string for the user who is being authentcated.</param>
    /// <returns>DriveService used to make requests against the Drive API</returns>
    public static PeopleService AuthenticateOauth(string clientSecretJson, string userName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("userName");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientSecretJson))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("clientSecretJson");
            if (!File.Exists(clientSecretJson))
                throw new Exception("clientSecretJson file does not exist.");

            // These are the scopes of permissions you need. It is best to request only what you need and not all of them
            string[] scopes = new string[] { PeopleService.Scope.UserPhonenumbersRead,  //View your phone numbers
                                             PeopleService.Scope.UserAddressesRead,     //View your street addresses
                                             PeopleService.Scope.UserBirthdayRead,      //View your complete date of birth
                                             PeopleService.Scope.ContactsReadonly,      //View your contacts
                                             PeopleService.Scope.UserEmailsRead,        //View your email addresses
                                             PeopleService.Scope.UserinfoProfile,       //View your basic profile info
                                             PeopleService.Scope.UserinfoEmail,         //View your email address
                                             PeopleService.Scope.PlusLogin,             //Know your basic profile info and list of people in your circles.
                                             PeopleService.Scope.Contacts};             //Manage your contacts
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(clientSecretJson, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);

                // Requesting Authentication or loading previously stored authentication for userName
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                                                                         scopes,
                                                                         userName,
                                                                         CancellationToken.None,
                                                                         new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            }

            // Create Drive API service.
            return new PeopleService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "People Oauth2 Authentication Sample"
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Create Oauth2 account PeopleService failed" + ex.Message);
            throw new Exception("CreateServiceAccountPeopleFailed", ex);
        }
    }
```

This will return a PeopleService which you can then use to make requests against the people api.  Like requesting data from the user.

> var me = service.People.Get("people/me").Execute();

The you can add the google calendar scopes to it and your usercredentails will be good for google people service and a google calendar service.

I have some sample code for google calendar [here](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/Genreated-samples1.0/Calendar%20API/v3) as well.

**Update javascript issue:**

JavaScript does not contain a refresh token you will only have an access token.  FileDatastore isn't going to be able to understand that.   You will probably need to make your own implementation of [idatastore](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/a5288c4493a12791b46f7142efacb83c4fcacf58/Src/Support/GoogleApis.Core/Apis/Util/Store/IDataStore.cs).   My question for you will be how do you intend to handle when the access token has expired are you going to make some kind of call back to your JavaScript authorization code?

Comment: I receive authorization code from my javascript app so I can not do the whole neat AuthorizeAsync thing. So I need to get authorization token instead of code and ExchangeCodeForToken seems like the right way to go (besides its weird arguments).

Comment: JavaScript isn't going to contain a refresh token.   So I don't think you are going to be able to use the client library unless I hack some kind of idatastore that accepts a access token.... mmm interesting idea.

Comment: Do I want to know why you are using javascript like that?  on the off chance this might be helpful you can also do it yourself with out the library http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/

Comment: Seems like you're right about Javascript (if I'm not mistaken, it supports only implicit grant). Could you please hint me on how to make .NET API specify offline access_type?

Comment: The client library will do offline access pretty much automatically its kind of a feature.  http://www.daimto.com/googleplusapi-get-csharp/

Comment: Okay, it makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I looked through [AuthorizationCodeFlow source code](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Support/GoogleApis.Auth/OAuth2/Flows/AuthorizationCodeFlow.cs) and while userId is not used for Google Api requests (as expected), it's used to store results to DataStore. So if you just consume api call results, you may not pass userId, otherwise you have to have it.

Answer (score 0):

to exchange the authorization code by access_token, you need [from the docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)

1. code - The authorization code returned from the initial request.
2. client_id - The client ID obtained from the API Console.
3. client_secret - The client secret obtained from the API Console.
4. redirect_uri - One of the redirect URIs listed for this project in the API Console.
5. grant_type - As defined in the OAuth 2.0 specification, this field must contain a value of authorization_code.

Maybe where you're saying that expect `userId` is `client_id`...I don't know the library...maybe is a bug if it's say that expect a userId instead of client_id in this `ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync` method.