# Google OAuth2 code-flow approach for SPA + .NET Core backend implementation

Tags: c#, reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Hi community!

I'm stuck with my project. What I'm developing is a web application (with both front- and backend) which will use Google auth of my organisation. Application will be used internally - only by employees. I believe that problem is in usage of `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync` method from `Google.Apis.Auth` nuget, but I'm not sure, so I'll be a little too detailed in what I did. Moreover I failed to find good tutorial for creating SPA + .NET web service with Google OAuth2, so it might be used by somebody as shallow tutorial

For frontend I use React and for backend .NET Core. As far as I understood I have to use code-flow (**not** implicit!) approach to not to expose *client secret* whicj Google provide me for my app. Please, correct me if I mistaken, but for my case I should authenticate user in my SPA React application using only *cliennt ID* of my Google Cloud application, which will return me a code. Then I should pass that code to my backend .NET Core application, where I exchange it with access and refresh tokens, than store them to cookies and be able to access all of Google service's API I needed.

First thing I did is create new app in [Google API console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard), Internal in my case as it for organisation members only. Then I goes to [API library](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library) and enabled necessary APIs (Drive and Sheets in my case). Then I goes to [credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) and created new *OAuth 2.0 Client IDs* entry. I provide it with such a config:

**Authorized JavaScript origins**

- http://localhost
- http://localhost:5173

**Authorized redirect URIs**

- http://localhost
- http://localhost:5173

Then I created Vite+React (that's why port is 5173 - app runs on it by default) application and among other things I installed `@react-oauth/google` package . As far as I choose code-flow approach, I wrapped my app into `GoogleOAuthProvider` element, so my *App.js* looks like:

```
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google'
import Auth from './features/auth/Auth'

function App() {
  return (
    <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={config.googleClientId}>    
      <Auth />
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

Then I implemented my *Auth.tsx* component like this:

```
import { useGoogleLogin, } from '@react-oauth/google'
import { Button, } from '@mantine/core'

export default () => {
    const login = useGoogleLogin({
        onSuccess: codeResponse => {
            console.log(codeResponse)
        },
        flow: 'auth-code', // here I define flow mode
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', scopes I wanted to access - don't forget them to set up here
    });

    return (
        <Button onClick={() => login()}>
            Log in with Google
        </Button>
    )
}
```

Offtop, I use `useGoogleLogin` hook as it's suggested to do so in `@react-oauth/google` [package manual](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google#authorization-code-flow) and there is no way to do it with sweet looking `GoogleLogin` component from that package, right?..

So here I can run my React application and try to get authorization code. And it works great, thats an example of response payload I got from Google auth service:

```
{
  "code": "4/0A....................skip some symbols to keep secret..............9M_A",
  "scope": "email profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
  "authuser": "0",
  "prompt": "consent"
}
```

In fact I can change mode by changing `flow: 'implicit'` in my `useGoogleLogin` defenition. In that case I will receive `access_token`, but no refresh token, which limits me for backend interaction with Google and should not be used for my scenario (correect me if I'm wrong), so I use `flow: 'auth-code'`

Here I consider that my frontend app set up in a proper way

Then I goes to my backend. I created C# .NET Core WEB API application. I installed `Google.Apis` and `Google.Apis.Auth` nugets and made endpoint which is available at https://localhost:7161/api/auth/start. It receives code from my frontend app and should exchange it with access and refresh tokens. Here is a code behind it:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace SweetWebAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/auth")]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("start")]
        public async Task Start()
        {
            string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Drive, SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets, }; // I'm going to use spreadsheet for a while

            // here i hardcode user id, if i'm right might be any, but I will use Gmail address
            var userId = "b.........a@gmail.com";

            // here I define where Google nugets will store my user info, folder exist
            var fileDataStore = new FileDataStore("C://Google");


            // here I hardcore the code whick receives my frontend application from Google auth service
            // and which I shuld exchange with access and refresh tokens
            var Code = "4/0A....................skip some symbols to keep secret..............9M_A";

            // here I hardcode redirect URL which is defined in Google API console and which I use to receive code
            var redirectUrl = "http://localhost:5173";

            // here I hardcode my client ID which I also use in frontend app to receive code
            var clientId = "56.........................................9f.apps.googleusercontent.com";

            // here I hardcode my client secret
            var clientSecret = "GO...............................p6";

            try
            {
                // here I create GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow object
                var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = clientId,
                        ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                    },
                    Scopes = Scopes,
                    DataStore = fileDataStore,
                });

                // here I try to get access and refresh tockens from local storage 
                TokenResponse tokenResponse = await fileDataStore.GetAsync<TokenResponse>(userId);

                // if I fail to get tokens (first time it's always the case - there is just none of them)
                // I try to exchange code with tockens accessing Google auth service
                if (tokenResponse == null)
                {
                    tokenResponse = await flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync(
                        userId,
                        Code, 
                        redirectUrl, 
                        CancellationToken.None); // ❗❗❗ here I got error
                }
                UserCredential userCredential = new UserCredential(flow, userId, tokenResponse);
                
                // ...use credential object to access Google services...
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here I got error:

```
Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Bad Request", Uri:""
```

Well, have to say that interaction with Google Sheets itself from my backend code works well if I use Service accounts, but I need to do actions on behalf with user in my app

I also tried to tunnel my front and backend services with ngrock, updating redirect URLs, but it gives no success

With no inner exception or additional detailes. I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong. Is my approach for SPA and server core to interact with Google correct at all? Do I correctly understand *redirect URL* purpose? Did I forget to set up something in [Google API console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard)? **Main question - where I mistaken?**

Sometimes while I ask a question I find an answer, but this time that didn't happened. I face that problem for 4th day I guess , please help me

**UPD 1. Finally fixed**. Not sure what caused the problem, migh be one of two:

- quite short auth code lifespan, I failed to paste it manually and start project
- some random misconfiguration or wrong code, which impossible to determine now

Anyway, now code exchanging works well, and looks like all snippets on above are correct

But now I face two another problems.

1. How I can determine userid to store file locally via `FileDataStore`? I can get it from access token, but I dont have it at first `TokenResponse tokenResponse = await fileDataStore.GetAsync<TokenResponse>(userId);` call. Should I make separate request to get user's email at frontend before sending auth code to backend? And if user log in from different browsers - will something crash?
2. I try to access Google Drive content using such code:

   ```
    DriveService driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = userCredential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });
    var gdRequest = driveService.Files.List();
    gdRequest.PageSize = 1000;
    var gdResponse = gdRequest.Execute();
   ```

`userCredential` reused from previous snippet, `ApplicationName` matched one from Google Console (even though thats not required AFAIK)

And I got error while executing query:
`"The service drive has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. Request had insufficient authentication scopes."`

In Google Console at *OAuth consent screen* page I set up 5 scopes:
[image: OAuth consent screen scopes]

Both Drive and Sheets apps are enabled. And when i create `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow` I also define both Drive and Sheets scopes (checo out first C# snippet in question). But I receive that error.

What makes me confused is that response payload I got from Google auth service do not return Drive and Sheets scopes (check out snippet above). But I triple checked them - they are set at consent screen. Also in local file created by `FileDataStore` there is no Drive and Sheets stores. I tried to delete that file and repeat auth process to let regenerate it with code from snippets, but still there is only such scopes:

```
{
    ...
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
    ...
}
```

I tried to add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` manually and tried to access Drive via API (without exchanging code to apply added manually scopes), but it makes no sense. What I do wrong?

**UPD 2. Fixed insufficient scopes error** Turned out that I have to set up scopes while requesting auth code while using `useGoogleLogin` hook:

```
scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
```

So the only question left is **how to set up correct `userId` that used in `fileDataStore.GetAsync<TokenResponse>()` and `flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync()` methods?**

**UPD 3. Found a solution for setting userId prior to access code exchanged with tokens** What I do is generate some random GUID at frontend and send it with auth code got from Google to my backend. At backend I first complete code from snippets above with that GUID, then get user info, delete GUID entry and store new with email as `userId`, and then send that `userId` to frontend as response:

```
// exchanging code with token and store it with GUID as userId
...
var oauthSerivce = new Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2.Oauth2Service(
    new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = userCredential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });

var userInfo = await oauthSerivce.Userinfo.Get().ExecuteAsync();

await fileDataStore.DeleteAsync<TokenResponse>(requestPayload.UserId);
await fileDataStore.StoreAsync<TokenResponse>(userInfo.Email, tokenResponse);
...
// send response to backend...
```

Not sure if it suppose to be so, looks way too unnatural from DX perspective, but there is no way to get email at frontend without second authorization process made by user, but with implicit flow, which looks more unatural from both DX and UX perspective. Wonder if email is really good to use it as `userId`. Anyway thats the best I can find right now. If you have any thoughts - please write them. Later I'll update question to make it more reusable by other developers. Thanks everyone who participated!

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Data%2FRepositories%2FAccountRepository.cs#L216) an example using Identity. [Here's](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src%2FSecurity%2FAuthentication%2FGoogle%2Fsrc%2FGoogleHandler.cs) the internal code for google

Comment: Authorization code can only be used once saving it seams unwise

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo looks like it's not only should be used onece, but also within minute or even less. And when I manually copy code and paste it to my backend project it expires. Soon I rewrite it as intented with no manual operations. Btw Linda, thank you for your articles about Google OAuth process, they helped me alot

Comment: Last I checked it expires in five minutes

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo found similar to my last question of this topic with your solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874310/google-api-requires-userid-before-i-have-access-token. But I still do not get from where do you pick userId to pass to AuthenticateOauth method

Comment: You should be aware that the Google api .net client has extremally limited to the point that i dont use it becouse its mostly broken.  Support for asp .net web applications.  There are noted issues for it over on the github issue forum.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo wow I didn't realize it yet, but anyway I cannot switch to any other backend except .NET. But I'll took that fact into consideration, thanks

Comment: Yeah but you can code the calls to the api yourself.   and handel the oauth directly with the offical microsoft libraries instead.